# How can I have Chrome not escape search terms when searching from the Omnibar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, opensearch

Currently Chrome navigates to `http://site.com/#!/search/search%20terms` when [searching directly from the Omnibar](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/webmasters-faq.html#osdd). Is there a way to have it navigate to `http://site.com/#!/search/search terms` instead? (One does not normally escape hash fragments)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to have it navigate to http://site.com/#!/search/search terms instead?

No

> (One does not normally escape hash fragments)

One usually does. Raw spaces are not allowed in URLs.

Comment: [Try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abrkn/qJ2B9/) to verify my claim

Comment: @abrkn — What claim? Are you suggesting that because you can give Chrome an invalid URI directly, its search feature should be able to generate an invalid URI?